# SFTP Inbound channel does not download files

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp, channel

I want to download txt files from the sftp server but my inbound channel just creates folder and does not download files into the directory. Once it is connected to the SFTP server then it gives the error. Kindly see the stacktrace.
I am using spring integration 4.

Here is my app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd                          
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration   
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">                    


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.canaldigital.tsi.bank" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:settings.properties" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="printMessage" fixed-delay="600000" initial-delay="3000"/>
        <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="checkStatus" fixed-delay="600000" initial-delay="2000"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />



    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${sftp.password}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.serverPort}"/>

        <!-- <property name="privateKey" value="${sftp.private.keyfile}"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sftp.passphrase}"/> -->

    </bean>

    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
<!--             <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
             <property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="1000"/>  -->    
    </bean>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="requestChannel"
            filename-pattern="*.txt"
            remote-directory="/home/oracle/IBSTOBANK/DNB/Norway/Outgoing/"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="file:src/main/resources/InboudSftpFiles"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'"
            temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
            delete-remote-files="false">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>


    <int:channel id="requestChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>


    <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
      <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

StackTrace:

```
SEVERE: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:118)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:310)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:354)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:187)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:167)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:349)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for oracle 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:987)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPassword.start(UserAuthPassword.java:91)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:241)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: It's not Spring Integration issue, so check, please, here http://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username and here http://serverfault.com/questions/36291/how-to-recover-from-too-many-authentication-failures-for-user-root. Or even just do Googling yourself!